# How to set AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds by platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin, absolutelayout

I'm using an absolute layout in my application and I want, for each element in the layout, a specific position and size depending the platform.

I find an other question where it was said that to use

```
<Label.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
```

But it my case, the `AbsoluteLayout` property doesn't exist if I write it between `<...>`

So, It is possible to set the property `LayoutBounds` by platform ?

I'm using Xamarin 4.4.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{OnPlatform Android='0,0,1,1', iOS='0,0,.5,.5'}"`

I believe that should work, but i haven't tested it. You just need to use `OnPlatform`  and provide the desired values for each platform you want to cover.

Edit: Just tested this. It works.

Comment: Thank's, its perfect !